# Usable hierarchical dropdown in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, usability, html-select, cascadingdropdown

I've got a mostly usability problem.

I've got a long list of hiearchical categories (200+) of archeological findings. When user posts his finding, he needs to select one category from this list:

- Bronze age
- - Household tools
- - Jewelry
- - Military
- - - Spears
- - ...
- Middle Ages
- - Jewlery
- - Religious artifacts
- - ...
- WW2
- - Germany
- - - Military
- - - - Badges
- - - - - Infantry
- ...

The list can't be cut/divided without information loss so I want to keep it as it is.

How to make it more usable? Typical 2 use cases are:

1. Selection **level after level** (first decide if it's Bronze Age, Middle Age, ... then if it's Jewlery, Military, ... then if it's Spears, ...)
2. **Search** (user knows that it's a necklace but doesn't know if it's Early or Late Middle Ages, etc.)

How to combine those two? Are there any existing solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use more than one drop down, for example, user selects Bronze Age in the first drop down, then selects Military in the second one and then Spears...

Comment: Using [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin maybe?  
You will be able to make a **level after level** search, and for each level, have a search possibility. In that way, if user just know the last level text, he can type it, and when only one row match, you could autoselect others levels.

Comment: [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup)?

Comment: IMO, have an autocomplete textbox with a search icon next to it that brings up a modal-window containing collapsible tree with the info above.

Comment: Implement all variants and ask your users.

Comment: - <optgroup> allows to select just leafs in the tree. I need possibility to select even node (e.g. Bronze Age)
- I tried autocomplete but the problem is that you see just the name of the category, not in which part of tree it is. So you type "jewelry", you see 2x "jewelry" but you don't see where these 2 categories belong

Comment: One possible solution came to my mind - a copy of file manager. In Windows Explorer, there're folders with + sign if the folder can be expanded. And the're also a search box looking in all subfolders from current position. But implementing this will be harder.

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, to sort out the first use case you can do something like this in your HTML:

```
Age: 
<select name='age' id='age' onchange="showRelevantRuleDropdown(this,1);">
     <option value='0'>Bronze Age</option>
     <option value='1'>Middle Age</option>
     ...
</select>

<select name='BronzeAge' id='BronzeAge' onchange="showRelevantRuleDropdown(this,1);">
     <option value='0'>Household tools</option>
     <option value='1'>Jewelry</option>
     ...
</select>

<select name='MiddleAge' id='MiddleAge' onchange="showRelevantRuleDropdown(this,1);">
     <option value='0'>Jewlery</option>
     <option value='1'>Religious artifacts</option>
     ...
</select>

...

<script language='JavaScript'>
showRelevantRuleDropdown(document.getElementById('age'),1);
</script>
```

Using the Javascript below:

```
function showRelevantRuleDropdown(elem, restore) {
    // Show one SELECT element (elem) between Option 1 or Option 2
    // If the parameter restore is 1, the hidden element is restored to its default value
    if (elem.selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById('BronzeAge').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('MiddleAge').style.display = 'inline';
        if (restore == 1) {
            document.getElementById('BronzeAge').getElementsByTagName('option')['0'].selected = 'selected';
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('MiddleAge').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('BronzeAge').style.display = 'inline';
        if (restore == 1) {
            document.getElementById('MiddleAge').getElementsByTagName('option')['0'].selected = 'selected';
        }
    }
}
```

This works for one level deep but could be easily extended.

I have the code in codepen if you want to use it: http://codepen.io/ophintor/pen/FaHbh

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can combine an autocomplete model with the hierarchy that you need to use. See image below.

Then, the users don't need to lookup or navigate the entire tree to select the item they want to select, without lose the hierarchy context. I think this meets the advanced users needs.

Nevertheless, you should provide a way to navigate in the tree (showing the entire tree) to attend the novice users to. Maybe it could be done putting an icon/text link next to the search box.

[image: Wireframe example]

Unfortunately, I don't find something like this implemented anywhere.